# Propagating model changes to a Parent Controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a an angularJS application and would try to simulate a Asana.com feature.

The scenario is the following:

[image: Asana]

I have a MainController for my application in the body tag, and inside this controller I populate my names in my sidebar:

```
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'NamesService', function($scope, NamesService) {
    $scope.names = NamesService.query();
    ...
};
```

When I click on any name (for example, Anna), my application change the route and in inject the name-edit.html template in my ng-view, represented by the content area on the picture above. I have a input used to change from Anna to Carol and a update button. When I hit the update button, It fires a function that updates in my database, changes Anna to Carol in my content area (represented by the yellow arrow position) but doesn't change the red arrow position in my sidebar.

I tried to call the following code again inside my success update callback, but doesn't work

```
$scope.names = NamesService.query();
```

I'd like to know how to propagate the child controller to the parent controller, changing Anna to Carol inside $scope.names. Is it possible to do this, without reloading $scope.names?

Comment: This link (http://codepen.io/brian-baum/full/BqEyL/) does something similar that I'm trying to achieve, but the list of contacts doesn't come from a service, like mine. In this scenario, they are changing the model inside the list. I'd like to change the model inside the child controller, then the contact list reloaded inside the main controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use event system of Angular using `$scope.$emit('eventName', eventData)` un your child controller to pass data up on the hierarchy.

```
//child, assuming you have promise callback
NamesService.query().then(function(data){
   $scope.$emit('eventName', data)
})
```

And in your parent controller have the following

```
//parent
$scope.$on('eventName', function(event, data){
   $scope.names = data;
})
```

Comment: Nice solution! I tried now $scope.$parent.names = NamesService.query(); inside my success update callback and it works, but I don't understand. If I have the parent controller $scope access inside my child controller, only $scope.names = NamesService.query(); should works, right?

Comment: $scope.$parent.names should be also possible; but I just proposed event system as more controllable and flexible

Comment: @shershen: Any idea how this will be done when 2.0 comes out?  Isn't $scope being removed?

Comment: @G.Deward for that case you can use shared service like a general event bus between app modules

Comment: @shershen : that's what I've been trying to do.  I removed `$scope` from my controllers months ago.  However, once a value is set in my parent (eg `vm.item = svc.item`) I cannot ever change `vm.item` from another controller.  If I do `svc.item = newItem` the change is not reflected in the top-level controller's instance of `vm.item`.  :(