# How to change parent controller's object instance using an AngularJS service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm using nested controllers and UI-Router.  My top level controller, called `MainCtrl`, is set in my app's `index.html` file.  If the `MainCtrl` uses a service, to pass data around, how can I change an instance of an object in the `MainCtrl` from a child controller **without** using `$scope`?

This is basically what I have (typed from memory):

```
var mainCtrl = function (ProfileSvc) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.profile = ProfileSvc.profile;
};

var loginCtrl = function (ProfileSvc, AuthSvc) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.doLogin = function (form) {
        if (form.$error) { return; }
        AuthSvc.login(form.user, form.pass).
            .then(function(response) {
                ProfileSvc.profile = response.data.profile;
            }, function(errResponse) {
                // error
            }            
    };
};
```

User @shershen posted a reply to another question that gave me the idea to use `$scope.$on` and an event, however I really do not want references to `$scope` in my code:
[Propagating model changes to a Parent Controller in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241523/propagating-model-changes-to-a-parent-controller-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

I think without using `$scope` you may want to use the `Controller as ctrl` in your views. So...

```
var mainCtrl = function (ProfileSvc) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.profile = ProfileSvc.profile;
  vm.updateProfile = function(profileAttrs) { 
    vm.profile = ProfileSvc.update(profileAttrs);
  }
};
```

Then in the view, something along the lines of:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
  <button ng-click="main.updateProfile({ name: 'Fishz' })">
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar on a project and ended up using $cacheFactory. First just load it up as a service with something like:

```
myApp.factory('appCache', function($cacheFactory) {
      return $cacheFactory('appCache');
});
```

Then make sure you inject appCache into your controllers and then in your controllers you can call the cache service's put and get methods to store and retrieve your object.

In my case the parent view and child view both can change the object I'm caching, but the user only can commit from the parent.